# not working laravel task sheduler on WAMP localhost

Tags: php, windows, laravel-5, wampserver

I am working with laravel 5.6 and going to make task schedule to delete a records witch  old than 15 days from now. so, I have CustomCommand.php file in app->Console->Commands folder and handle function is this,

```
public function handle()
{
    $now = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
    DB::table('vehicles')
         ->where('created_at', '<', $now->subDays(15))
         ->delete();
    $this->info('All old advertisments are deleted sucessfully');
}
```

and My kernel.php is like this,

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{

    $schedule->command('custom:command')->hourly();
}
```

but My vehicles table older than 15days records do not delete as shedule... how to fix this problem?

Comment: No any ideas to solve this matter

Comment: You need a cron job to run Laravel Scheduler, and Windows doesn't have cron jobs. Check out this thread, though, with some info about how to set up a scheduled Windows task to do it: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/running-schedulerun-on-windows